# Table border radius with table body scroll

Tags: html, css

I trying to create a table with border radius.In that table the thead should be fixed at the top and the tbody only scrolls. Applied a custom styling for the scroll bar. The issue is, when i apply border radius ,it is working fine in the left side of the table.But on the right side it is not working properly due the scroll bar.

Is there anyway to fix this or is it possible to move the scrollbar inside the table,so that the border radius will be fine on bot sides

```css
  .table-border{
     border:1px solid #dddddd;
     border-right:none;
     border-radius:20px;
     overflow:hidden;
     height:300px;
     overflow-y:scroll;
  }
  thead th{
     position: sticky !important;
     top:0;
     background:#333;
     color:#fff;
  }
  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }

  td, th {
    border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
 
   /* width */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
  }
  /* Track */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1; 
  }
  /* Handle */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background:#E1E1E1; 
  }
  /* Handle on hover */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #999; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="table-border">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```